# Create a React HOC that provides context data from server

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I want to create a HOC like react-router that provides some context related data to components. The context data needs to be fetched from server.

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

export function withSearchContext(ComponentToWrap) {
  return class extends Component {

    //should actually come from server
    state = {
      searchContext: {
        key: "adedd34ddDdd1"
      }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getContextFromServer();
    }

    getContextFromServer() {
      this.props.getContextFromServer().then(response => {
        this.setState({searchContext: response.data});
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ComponentToWrap {...this.props} searchContext={this.state.searchContext} />
      );
    }
  };
}
```

I am using it like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withSearchContext } from '../../Context';

@withSearchContext
class AccountDetail extends Component<{}, {}> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this.props.searchContext);
  };

   render() {
     if(this.props.searchContext.key){
      return (
        <div className="detail-view flex-container">
          {this.props.searchContext.key}
        </div>
     } 
     return <div> Loading ... </div>;
    );
   }
}
```

The problem is the HOC gets called for every component I wrap it with. Consequently, the call to server happens multiple times. However, I just need the HOC to run once and provide the context to any component that uses the HOC. How can this be achieved in React?

Comment: I see you have redux in your tags. Are you using redux?

Comment: @gretro yes I am using Redux as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Redux` it's a better idea to store the response object in the store and access it through connected components. The rest of the answer is how it could be done but it's not suggested. In the `context` approach you need to make sure the req/res is completed before rendering the application which means call `ReactDOM.render` after you get a response.

You could achieve this with a `<SearchContextProvider />` component that will utilise React [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Then use the HOC to return components that are aware of the context. Instantiate the provider once wrapping your app and pass the response object as a prop. Following is a high level solution.

#### SearchContextProvider.js

```
class SearchContextProvider extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    search: PropTypes.object
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return { search: this.props.search };
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children; // React16
  }
}
```

#### App.js

```
<SearchContextProvider search={data}>
  <App />
</SearchContextProvider>
```

#### withSearchContext.js

```
export function withSearchContext(ComponentToWrap) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      search: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <ComponentToWrap 
          {...this.props} 
          search={this.context.search} 
        />
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Redux. So do you mean that it's better to dispatch an action creator in some higher level component (App component perhaps) to get the initial context and then to store in Redux as a single source of truth? Is it ok that multiple components access the Search Reducer state in their mapStateToProps? I mean I was hoping to make components access from their respective reducer that's usually associated with container components.

Comment: You need to think an appropriate shape for your store. For example if some initial data are used all over the app like `AppSettings` it is ok for many components to map to them in `mapStateToProps`.